# Azure Storage Analytics Local Development

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-storage

I was wondering if there is a way to enable storage analytics for development storage? So I can see some statistics about the test I ran?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage analytics for development storage is not available currently. You would need to run your tests against cloud storage and collect the data there.